# How do I combine mutate_all and ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to iterate over all columns of a data.frame with mutate_all() and then selectively change values using ifelse().

```
testdf <- data.frame("a"=c(1,2,3), "b"=c(4,5,6), "c"=c(7,8,9))

mutate_all(testdf, ifelse(.>9,10,.))
```

But this does not work. I always get "object '.' not found". How do I refer to the individual values passed through the mutate_all() function? I thought the '.' worked that way? This works:

```
mutate_all(testdf, funs(.*2))
```

Comment: You have to pass a function like in your second example, not just an expression. See the examples at the bottom of `?mutate_all` where `funs()` is used.

Comment: `mutate_all(testdf, funs(ifelse(. > 9, 10, .)))` works for me. On a side note - there are no values `> 9 ` in your `testdf`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the part I did not realize. I HAVE to use a function and can't use expressions. I misunderstood the "object '.' not found" error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
testdf %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(x>9,10,x))

testdf %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(.>9,10,.)))

testdf %>% mutate_all(testdf, ~ifelse(.>9,10,.))

testdf %>% mutate_all(~ pmin(., 10))

testdf %>% mutate_all(pmin, 10)

testdf %>% mutate_all(~ replace(., . > 9, 10))

testdf %>% replace(. > 9, 10)
```

Last two are per Ronak Shah comment below.

### Update

Since this question was asked dplyr 1.0.0 has come out and introduced a new `across` function which is used with `mutate` and is now preferred over the mutate_* functions.

```
testdf %>% mutate(across(, ~ pmin(., 10)))
```

Comment: Could you add some more options? Seems a bit limited for choice.